# how to intent to native app after sending message from inbuilt message app

Tags: android, sms, message

Am using inbuilt message application in my app to send message, but after sending message it stuck there only,while sending message it should intent back to my application how can i do it.

```
 public void sendSmsIntent(String phoneNumber) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent2.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
            startActivity(intent2);

        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call sendSMS() method wherever you want to send SMS;

```
 private void sendSMS()
        {

            PendingIntent sent = this.createPendingResult(SENT, new Intent(),   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendDataMessage(strcontactnumber, null, SMS_PORT, messageText.getBytes(), sent, null);
        }
```

onActivityResult();

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    String toast = null;
    switch (requestCode)
    {
    case SENT :
        switch (resultCode)
        {
        case RESULT_OK :
            toast = "OK";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE :
            toast = "Generic Failure";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF :
            toast = "Radio Off";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU :
            toast = "Null Pdu";
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    if (toast != null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

It will directly send sms from your app without calling native app

```
And if you want to return back to your app by your code then

It is possible. Just need to add the following extra to your intent:

sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
```

Comment: can i use "start activity for result" apart from "start activity" is it help full .?

Comment: i did that ,, are you happy.??

Comment: hi,, from inbuilt sms app on clicking send button an calling one method and on pressing back button am calling one more method am using onBackPressed() but still i cont able to meet my goal, do you have any solution..?

Comment: What you exactly want , sorry but i didn't get you

Comment: hi i want to send that code but it is not possible to add that code in comment how can i share that code with you,,

Comment: hi as you said am using intent2.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true); to navigate back to my app when i pressed on send button,,, but if i pressed on back button then also message is sending,, on backpressed  i dont want to send that msg can uhelp me,,,

Comment: you can call onBackpresses() method and perform any action whatever you want.

Comment: i cont  Override onBackpresses() because am using  CallBackInterFace [here response is coming form cloud server] so i cont able override CallBackInterFace, do u have other option